# How to implement a WHERE clause on a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, where-clause, having-clause

I have this database table   “ MyTable”  contain data as shown below,   I want to fetch data from it using where clause  as  so that I can have a  view as on “MyView2.

```
MyTable

StudentID   courseID    scores  term    Academic year
A001         PHY          70    1         2016
A004         MATH         60    2         2014
A001         CHEM         80    1         2016
A002         MATH         72    1         2016
A002         CHEM         61    1         2016
A004         PHY          49    2         2014
A001         MATH         89    1         2016
A002         PHY          65    1         2016
A004         CHEM         71    2         2014
```

So far I have used this piece of code to bring these results on “MyView “

```
 <?php
     ……………………………………
  SELECT stid, MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'MATH' THEN marks END) MATH ,MAX(    CASE WHEN courseid 'CHEM' THEN marks END) CHEM,MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'PHY' THEN marks END) PHY FROM MyTable   GROUP BY stid ORDER BY 1"
         …………………………
  ?>
```

MyView

```
   StudentID    MATH    CHEM    PHY
    A001         70       80    89
    A002         72       61    65
    A004         60       71    49
```

Where and how should I implement “where Clause” to bring results  based on the academic year 2016, term 1 to have  results on table “MyView2 “

MyView2

```
   StudentID    MATH    CHEM    PHY
    A001         70       80    89
    A002         72       61    65
```

Comment: SELECT 
      stid
    , MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'MATH' THEN marks END) MATH 
    , MAX( CASE WHEN courseid 'CHEM' THEN marks END) CHEM
    , MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'PHY' THEN marks END) PHY 
FROM MyTable   GROUP BY stid 
WHERE stid = 'A004'
ORDER BY 1

Comment: actually is not a single data, is the group of data  thus why i want to fetch it based on term and academic year so i can't fetch it by studentiD @ scais Edge

Comment: Personally, I think it's daft to execute a query this way if you're just going to process the result in PHP afterwards

Comment: let say i want to fetch all  data from term 1 and academic year is 2016 how can i do that@ scaisEgge

Comment: am not much good at English can you tell what you mean @Strawberry

Comment: i have updated the question what if i want to  fetch all data from term 1 and academic year is 2016 how can i do that @Andrew Li

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler and more flexible if you used the following query, and handled all further processing in PHP or JavaScript...

```
SELECT stid
     , courseid 
     , marks 
     FROM MyTable
 ORDER BY stid, courseid
```

Comment: thanks for respond, will it work without where because  i want fetch specific data from group of them based on year and term( academic year  2016 and term is 1) @ Strawberry

Comment: You can add a WHERE if you like. If the data set isn't too large then you can do the filtering in PHP or JavaScript instead

Comment: ok, let me try to work on it..  thanks for your time@Strawberry